# How to Hide Toolbar

Tags: sharepoint-2007, toolbar

Creating a ListViewWebPart. I am able to set custom view and everything else. I have a need to set Toolbar to None. How do I do that? (Using C# console app)

Comment: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/changing_the_toolbar_on_a_shar.html

Comment: I followed this guy and it worked.  http://sharepointstudio.com/People/MarkStokes/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=27

Answer (score 1):

[Changing (or removing) the Toolbar from a ListViewWebPart](http://sharepointstudio.com/People/MarkStokes/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=27) - I followed this guy and it worked